# bibtex - how to check .bst for errors

Tags: bibtex

I'm trying to create a bibliography with bibtex. It took me quite a long time to find good styling file for bibtex which suits my needs. The deal is, that it hadn't ONLINE reference function, so I used another .bst file. After I copied this fc. it was calling another, so I copied it as well - this exact problem was gone. I'm using XeLatex.
BUT NOW IT SAYS:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \texttt .
<inserted text>
\par
l.159 \bibliography{literatura}
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.160
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.160
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\par ...m \@noitemerr {\@@par }\fi \else {\@@par }
\fi
l.160
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
[30
] [31
]
! LaTeX Error: \begin{thebibliography} on input line 1 ended by \end{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.171 \end{document}
Your command was ignored.
```

AND WHAT I HAVE ADDED:

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
{ "" }
{ new.block "Dostupn{\'{e}}~z: $\texttt{<{" url * "}>}$" * }
if$
}

FUNCTION {online} %  CHANGE mudrd8mz 2005-10-12 addign new item type
{ output.bibitem
format.authors output
new.block
format.btitle " [online]" * output
new.sentence
publisher missing$
'skip$
{ publisher output }
if$
year missing$
'skip$
{ format.date "year" output.check }
if$
new.sentence
cited missing$
'skip$
{ "[cit.~" cited * "]" * output }
if$
new.sentence
note output
new.sentence
format.url output
fin.entry
}
```

THIS IS WHAT BIB ENTRY SHOULD LOOK LIKE FOR .BST I COPIED FROM:

```
@ONLINE{eurydiceictedu2000,
author = "Eurydice",
title = "Information and communication technology in the education systems in
Europe: National education policies, Curricula, Teacher training",
cited = "8.\,6.\,2004",
year = "2004",
url = "http://www.eurydice.org/Doc_intermediaires/others/en/ict.html"
}
```

I AM WELL AWARE THAT THERE IS SOME PROBLEM WITH MY MODIFIED BST FILE, SO I WOULD LIKE TO ASK... IS THERE A WAY TO CHECK IT FOR ERRORS (from what I understood 'latex makebst' isn't the one)? I will gladly provide more info, or files.

EDIT:

**MY ENTRY:**

```
@ONLINE{houser,
author = {Pavel Houser},
title = {Collegium pro arte antiqua},
cited = {30.\,6.\,2014},
year = {2014},
url = {http://www.collegium.cz/waldorf/hudba/kurzy/rytmicke%20texty.pdf}
}
```

As you can see I tried to replace **""** with **{}**, but to no avail... so I suppose that they have the same meaning for compiler.

**BBL ENTRY:**

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{houser}
{\sc Houser, P.}
\newblock {\em Collegium pro arte antiqua} [online]. 2014.
[cit.~30.\,6.\,2014].
\newblock Dostupn{\'{e}}~z:
$\texttt{<{http://www.collegium.cz/waldorf/hudba/kurzy/rytmicke%20texty.pdf}>}$.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: The bst language manual is in most tex distributions as `texdoc btxhak` or online as http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/bibtex/base/btxhak.pdf

Comment: why are you adding `$` around texttt? (although that isn't the cause of the error). the error is from latex rather than bibtex, so can you post the entry in the .bbl file generated or that bibtex entry. presumably it has a mismatched `{`

Comment: Thank you for response, Ive added the requested code to the bottom of my question. –

Comment: Oh that was my initial guess (that you had a `%`) but the bibtex entry that you showed did not have one! As you see in the syntax colouring on this site `%` is the comment character so latex never saw the end of the URL or the closing `}}` use the `url` package. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 3):

The error is unrelated to bibtex (other than it was bibtex that generated the bad latex)
In

```
$\texttt{<{http://www.collegium.cz/waldorf/hudba/kurzy/rytmicke%20texty.pdf}>}$.
```

The `%` is TeX's comment character so latex just sees

```
$\texttt{<{http://www.collegium.cz/waldorf/hudba/kurzy/rytmicke
```

so the `\texttt` and the math `$` are never closed and you get the errors that you quoted.

the `$` were never doing anything useful, so they could just be deleted, but rather than `\texttt` you need a command that deals with special characters in URL such as `%`, `~` and `#`. Obvious choice is `\url` from the `url` (or `hyperref`) package that will make those characters safe and also allow line breaking at good places like `/`.

So something like

```
{ new.block "Dostupn{\'{e}}~z: \url{" url * "}" * }
```

and

```
\usepackage{url}
```

in your document (or package).

Comment: I did what you’ve suggested and it finally works!Thanks!